# DevExpress column standard showpop menu add custom copy item it'S under cells

Tags: c#, devexpress, menuitem, right-click, datagridcolumnheader

I want to add a custom menu item into standard popshow menu, which copies first cell value column and copies to its under cells. It should copy just its under cells.

I searched some things but couldn't find an example how to do. I found some examples but couldn't understand.

I want to do something like what I attached as a screenshot.

Can you help please?

I want to get something like that:

[image: I want to something like that]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The easiest way to accomplish this goal is to handle the
>   [PopupMenuShowing](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_PopupMenuShowingtopic) event. To get a grid cell value at the mouse
>   click point, use the [GridView.GetFocusedValue](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_GetFocusedValuetopic) method.

I suggest you to go through DevExpress Threads:
[How to achieve to right click cell and copy cell's value](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q481715/how-to-achieve-to-right-click-cell-and-copy-cell-s-value)
[GridView Copy Context Menu](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q325604/gridview-copy-context-menu)
[Default Right Click Menu Xtra Grid Cell](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q136957/default-right-click-menu-xtra-grid-cell)
[Right-click focus cell and show context menu](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q257821/right-click-focus-cell-and-show-context-menu)
[How to add a new item to the default context menu of the GridView active editor](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q524535/how-to-add-a-new-item-to-the-default-context-menu-of-the-gridview-active-editor)